# MySQL: Optimizing JOINs to find non-matching records

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, query-optimization, inner-join

We have a host management system (let's call it CMDB), and a DNS system, each using different tables. The former syncs to the latter, but manual changes cause them to get out of sync. I would like to craft a query to find aliases in CMDB that do NOT have a matching entry in DNS (either no entry, or the name/IP is different)

Because of the large size of the tables, and the need for this query to run frequently, optimizing the query is very important.

Here's what the tables look like:

```
cmdb_record: id, ipaddr
cmdb_alias: record_id, host_alias
dns_entry: name, ipaddr
```

cmdb_alias.record_id is a foreign key from cmdb_record.id, so that one IP address can have multiple aliases.

So far, here's what I've come up with:

```
SELECT cmdb_alias.host_alias, cmdb_record.ipaddr
FROM cmdb_record
INNER JOIN cmdb_alias ON cmdb_alias.record_id = cmdb_record.id
LEFT JOIN dns_entry
    ON dns_entry.ipaddr = cmdb_record.ipaddr
    AND dns_entry.name = cmdb_alias.host_alias
WHERE dns_entry.ipaddr IS NULL OR dns_entry.name IS NULL
```

This seems to work, but takes a very long time to run. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: As requested, here are the SHOW CREATE TABLEs. There are lots of extra fields that aren't particularly relevant, but included for completeness.

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cmdb_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_version` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipaddr` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipaddr_numeric` decimal(40,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `block_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `record_commented` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `mod_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_owner` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ipaddr` (`ipaddr`),
  KEY `cmdb_record_fe30f0f7` (`ipaddr`),
  KEY `cmdb_record_2b8b575` (`ipaddr_numeric`),
  KEY `cmdb_record_45897ef2` (`block_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `block_id_refs_id_ed6ed320` FOREIGN KEY (`block_id`) REFERENCES `cmdb_block` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=104427 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `cmdb_alias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `host_alias` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_cs NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `record_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cmdb_alias_fcffc3bb` (`record_id`),
  KEY `alias_lookup` (`host_alias`),
  CONSTRAINT `record_id_refs_id_8169fc71` FOREIGN KEY (`record_id`) REFERENCES `cmdb_record` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=155433 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_cs

Create Table: CREATE TABLE `dns_entry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rec_grp_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ipaddr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ttl` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `op` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `mod_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `whodunit` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `comments` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `dns_entry_a2431ea` (`domain_id`),
  KEY `dns_entry_52094d6e` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49437 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- need to see datatypes, indexes, engine, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, added that

Comment: I see 3 different datatypes for ipaddr; the most puzzling is `DECIMAL(40,0)`.

Comment: `deleted` is not needed; you could test `deleted_date IS NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: Are you dealing with IPv6?  39 characters is the limit.  Will you be looking at 'ranges' of IP addresses?  If so `11.22.33.44` won't be useful.

Comment: `cmdb_record` has a 'natural' PK with `ipaddr'; there is not much reason for adding a surrogate `id`.  I'm making these comments in hopes that you will simplify the schema before I tackle your question about `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have one already, create an index on `dns_entry(ipaddr, name)`.  This might be all you need to speed the query.

Comment: There was already an index on name, but there was no index on ipaddr. Adding an index to ipaddr drastically sped up this query to where it is now usable in repetitive situations. Thanks!